# No horizontal line under "Sign Up" tab in Stack Overflow and its international sites

Tags: bug, design, account-recovery

Missing underline for "Sign up" tab on the [account recovery page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery):

> [image: noline]

Observed on Stack Overflow and its international clones: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/, https://es.stackoverflow.com/, and https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Tested on FF, Chrome, IE.

Comment: Appears to happen only on Stack Overflow, checked here on MSE and in arqade, both are fine. (So maybe better post it on MSO instead)

Comment: @ShadowWizard related to ruSO also.

Comment: Oh, so all versions of SO. Better mention it in the report, IMO.

Comment: @ShadowWizard feel free to edit the post. My english is too slow yet.